# VoiceOver not reading list inside of a tooltip (Safari only)

Tags: safari, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

While doing accessibility sanity checks, I like to ensure to provide appropriate guidance for developers to correct anything that is reported as problematic or incorrect.

In this case, their implementation of a tooltip was incorrect. So I set to use MDN's documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Tooltip_Role) as a reference.

But before simply sharing that, I tested MDN's code example with VoiceOver myself, and I discovered something curious:

List elements (`<ul>` in MDN's example) are not actually read by the screen reader. I tested with VoiceOver on Chrome and Firefox, and they both read the tooltip content as expected.

Does anyone know if this is a Safari bug, or if there is anything to ensure to do in the markup to ensure the tooltip content is read?

Here is a link to test: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/jansensan/test-a11y-tooltip/blob/main/public/index.html

Here is the code: https://github.com/jansensan/test-a11y-tooltip/blob/main/public/index.html

---

Edit: To clarify, I currently tested this on macOS Ventura with Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. The issue of VoiceOver not reading the content happens on Safari (weirdly enough). It skips the list altogether (I added paragraphs , `<p>` before and after the list to see what it would read).

---

Edit 2: I used the keyboard with the TAB key to reach the field that has `aria-describedby="passwordRules1"` while having VoiceOver activated. In Safari, only the text paragraphs (`p`) were read, not the list items (`ul` and `li`), whereas Chrome and Firefox in did read them fine.

My understanding was that this was the appropriate way to ensure a screen reader would provide tooltip details to the screen reader user, and which is why I was confused why Safari did not read the content. I mean, lists are pretty basic elements.

Additionally, I stumbled upon this article that could highlight a potential related issue: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2019/01/12/lists-and-safari.html Although my example did not have such styling added.

Comment: I tried VoiceOver on **iOS** and was able to read the list elements. Did you only test VoiceOver on **MacOS**? Just trying to narrow things down. With VO on iOS, I swiped right until I got to the input field, then double tapped to cause the tooltip to appear, then swiped right to get into the tooltip, then was able to swipe right and hear "list start" and then swiped through the list items. To further help clarify, can you also describe the gestures you used in VO on MacOS? Just update your question, don't put your updates in this comment section.

Comment: I updated my description with the context of how I tested and got the issue.

Comment: You're still missing what gestures you're using to navigate to elements and what element you're navigating to when you **don't** hear the list structure. If you are listening to the "accessible description" of the input (b/c you have `aria-describedby`), then the list won't be announced. If you are listening to the "accessible name" of the tooltip, then you also won't hear the list structure because the name comes from the [tooltip content](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#namefromcontent) (w/o structure). But if you navigate through each element of the tooltip itself, you should hear the list.

Comment: andy & slogolicious: I believe this is a better implementation: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/jansensan/test-a11y-tooltip/blob/main/public/version-02/index.html In this version, the tooltip is read properly when reaching the field, the keyboard navigation works, and the mouse navigation works as well. Can't vouch for mobile yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: Works ok on iOS.  The only thing I'd change is add `aria-hidden="true"` to the X-close icon in the tooltip. It reads as "cross mark" and then also reads your sr-only text.  There's no need to read the icon. `<span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">❌</span>`

Comment: It's nice that the ESC key works to close the tooltip.  When you implement that, it also gives you the Z-scrub gesture on iOS to close the dialog for free.  That's a 2-finger "Z" shape.  See "[Dismiss an alert...](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/learn-voiceover-gestures-iph3e2e2281/ios#aria-iph00497a1bf)".

Answer (score 0):

There are two different situations here.

### Descriptions only need to be read as a flat string

According to [ARIA’s Text Equivalent Computation](https://w3c.github.io/accname/#mapping_additional_nd_te), exposure of the referenced structure is not required:

> The purpose of the computation is to create a perceivable label or description for alternative presentations, in the form of a flat string of space separated textual tokens.

So this concerns the text read when focus is on the input—provided the user activated announcement of descriptions in their settings.

### Reading the tooltips content by moving reading cursor onto it

If the reading cursor is moved onto the tooltip widget itself, the whole contents must be read, including structure. It would be surprising if Safari didn’t do that. If it doesn’t, it’s a bug.

### Tooltips must stay open on hover

Both tooltip examples have one issue, though: They fail [WCAG Success Criterion 1.4.13 Content on Hover or Focus](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/content-on-hover-or-focus.html#hoverable), because they close when trying to move the mouse pointer on them.

> **Hoverable**: If pointer hover can trigger the additional content, then the pointer can be moved over the additional content without the additional content disappearing;

It’s a reflex of mouse users to hover content they are reading, independent of screen reader use.

Comment: "It would be surprising if Safari didn’t do that." Indeed it is, which is why I opened this conversation. "Both tooltip examples have one issue, though [...]" Maybe I didn't copy all the code from MDN? Or maybe it's MDN's code that is incorrect? I really was not trying to create my own, but to test what is the suggested way.

Comment: Also, why do you say the hover does not work? I tested on Safari, Chrome and Firefox and the hover works on the input. How did you test?

Comment: I think what @andy means by "hover not working" is because when you hover and see the tooltip, while that part works, WCAG also requires the user be able to move the mouse to the tooltip text itself and still have the tooltip displayed. That's the part that doesn't work. That causes an issue for magnification users. They need to move the mouse, and thus their magnifying viewport, to the tooltip text in order to be able to read it. If the tooltip disappears when the mouse moves off the `<input>`, then the user will not be able to magnify the tooltip text.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious I tried to make that more clear in my answer. The MDN code did ignore that SC, I suggested the change to the page and also filed a bug report about the code example failing that SC.